# HTML5 Canvas - change color of previously drawn shapes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, overlay, overlap

I have various functions on my canvas that allow it to be drawn on. However, when lines overlap and get drawn over previously drawn spots, I want the color of the spot that was re-drawn over to change color to a darker shade. What would be the code I would write to evaluate whether or not a spot was drawn over?

Answer (score 2):

**You can use "Blending" to darken overlapping areas on your canvas**

The advantage of using blending is that you don't have to keep track of previously drawn strokes & fills.

[image]

If you don't care about supporting Internet Explorer/Edge, you can use `context.globalCompositeOperation="multiply"` which will darken by applying a multiply filter on new overlapping drawings. *(P.S. to Microsoft: Come on MS...give us more good stuff like Blending!).*

```
// For browser except IE/Edge...
// darken overlapping strokes using "multiply" compositing
ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.fillRect(100,100,100,100);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='multiply';
ctx.fillRect(75,150,100,100);
```

For IE/Edge, there is a "manual" multiply filter which involves reading each pixel's RGBA information using `context.getImageData` and doing the following computation against every red, green & blue color value. This manual method is considerably slower than using compositing.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// rgb values for skyblue
var r=135;
var g=206;
var b=235;

multiplyFilter(100,100,100,100,r,g,b);
multiplyFilter(75,150,100,100,r,g,b);



function multiplyFilter(x,y,width,height,newRed,newGreen,newBlue){
  var imgData=ctx.getImageData(x,y,width,height);
  var data=imgData.data;
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=4) {
    if(data[i+3]>0){
      data[i+0] = (data[i+0]*newRed)/255;
      data[i+1] = (data[i+1]*newGreen)/255;
      data[i+2] = (data[i+2]*newBlue)/255;
    }else{
      data[i+0]=newRed;
      data[i+1]=newGreen;
      data[i+2]=newBlue;
      data[i+3]=255;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData,x,y);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Darken overlaps using a "manual" multiply filter</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```